# How to create a Mysql trigger to update incoming row from new value?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger that will take a new incoming value, and chop it up, then update 2 other columns based upon the subtring values.  But I cannot figure out the syntax.

I have columns named main, sub, and title.

I would like to split up the incoming title, into the two other columns on insert.

Here is what I have so far.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT ON
    `table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.main = SUBSTRING(NEW.title, 5, 3);
    SET NEW.sub = SUBSTRING(NEW.title, 15, 9);
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: _"What am I getting wrong?"_ - if you're seeing an error message, post it here.

Comment: When I create the trigger, the trigger is created fine and fires without error.  But the problem is that it doesn't add the substring to the new columns.  The new columns are blank.  Hmm...  Let me check on Mysql 8.  I am doing this on Mysql 5.7.34.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I figured out what my problem was.  Apparently the the row is inserted and the column I needed is not inserted with the row.  It is updated later on and I was not aware of this.  So my trigger on insert was working fine.  It was updating the new columns with blank data because that's what it got on insert.

Answer (score 0):

The column I wanted to split up into two columns was blank during insert of the row, then updated shortly after.  I just needed to change my trigger to fire on update of that column.